# Disable sandbox in custom rule

Tags: sandbox, bazel, rule

How can I disable the sandbox in a custom Bazel rule?

I want the sandbox *always* disabled for every instantiation of this rule, without the user having to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating actions in the rule implementation, include the [`execution_requirements`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run.execution_requirements) dict argument containing a `no-sandbox` key with a value of `1`. This forces the action to never run in the sandbox.

```
def _impl(ctx):
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = [ctx.outputs.executable],
    command = "..",
    execution_requirements = {
      "no-sandbox": "1",
      "no-cache": "1",
      "no-remote": "1",
      "local": "1",
    },
  )
```

See the `tags` attribute on the [documentation for common build attributes](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common-attributes) for more information on these tags/requirements.